# Rails model holds several references of its own class type in the same table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, model, associations, ruby-on-rails-5.1

There seems to be no sequence of associations that work for this pattern:

Each user holds a reference to two OTHER users in the same table.

The `User` table contains two fields called `user_a_id` and `user_b_id`. I've been trying to get the following model associations to work:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_one :user_a, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "user_a_id"
    has_one :user_b, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "user_b_id"
end
```

The reference only needs to work in one direction. I simply want to use the model in the following way:

```
user.user_a.name
user.user_b.name
```

I won't ever need to access `user_a.parent_user`. I do not need that type of relationship.

The problem occurs when I reference `self.user_a` in the `before_save` callback. I basically get a recursive loop of SQL queries that eventually give me a `stack too deep` error.

Does anyone know what's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a solution. This may be an edge case BUT I needed to use `belongs_to` instead of `has_one` and I needed to remove the `id` from my table and the `foreign_key`. Also, because I was storing my references in a `before_save` callback, and they would have been empty during validation, I needed to add the parameter `optional: true`. This is the only association that allowed my program to reliably work:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user_a, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "user_a", optional: true
    belongs_to :user_b, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "user_b", optional: true
end
```

Hopefully that helps somebody!

Answer (score 2):

I just tried what you want to achieve. This is the ***migration*** for the users  table:

```rb
create_table :users do |t|
  t.string :name
  t.references :user_a
  t.references :user_b

  t.timestamps
end
```

Notice how this generates the following **schema.rb**

```rb
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "name"
  t.integer "user_a_id"
  t.integer "user_b_id"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  t.index ["user_a_id"], name: "index_users_on_user_a_id"
  t.index ["user_b_id"], name: "index_users_on_user_b_id"
end
```

In the User model I have

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :user_a, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "user_a_id"
  has_one :user_b, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "user_b_id"
end
```

After migrating I can do in my `rails console` the following:

```
User.create(
  name: "inception_user",
  user_a: User.create(name: "Adam"),
  user_b: User.create(name: "Berta")
)

inception_user = User.find_by_name "inception_user"

inception_user.user_a.name
=> "Adam"

inception_user.user_b.name
=> "Berta"
```

Everything works as expected with this setup. Please comment if you still have problems!
More information about self-joins: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#self-joins

Comment: I'll give that a try. The only difference there seems to be is that I didn't use t.references in my migration and I don't have the t.index calls. Do you think that makes a difference?

Comment: Ok, added the indexes and it didn't fix anything. To get more specific, I'm referencing the field self.user_a in the `:before_save` callback. This is what's causing the cyclical query. I'm not sure on the mechanism though ...

Comment: Have you tried executing the same code I did in the rails console, without the before_save callback?

Comment: Maybe you can add your exact error output to the question :)